# cpanel cronjob curl increase file size

Tags: bash, curl, cron

I created a bash script to run as a cronjob with Cpanel:

--------------content of cron.sh---------------------

```
#!/bin/bash
curl http://website.com/1.gif >> /home/myuser/public_html/directory/1.gif
```

------------ end of content -------------------------

I would expect curl to overwrite any existing files, but what occurs is that every time the cron job is executed the destination file doubles in size!

ex: after 1 cron:
1.gif size 50kb

after 2 cron:
1.gif size 100kb

and so on...

I would like simply to overwrite the target file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `>>` to `>`.  The `>>` is making it append to the file.